# prevent spam messages in a contact form

Tags: javascript, php, spam-prevention

I was wondering if i am taking the right approach as spam is still coming through. i currently have standard javascript validation which checks things like google recaptcha and required fields, but i also have a hidden field that is checked server side. the field below is checked if its been filled in and wont submit.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="contact_form">
```

i have done some research and believe that bots are now starting to read fields like hidden and `display:none;`. would a good approach be to move the field off screen for the user? any suggestions would be great.

Comment: If this is a real concern then a captcha is what you need. If you just want something that kinda works but not always then a normal off-screen input should be fine. No matter what you do there's always going to be a bot dev that will anticipate it and code for it. Not that captcha works 100% but it's probably better than a lot of other things you could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Captcha (I'm not a Robot)

I'm using it on my website and never had problems again with Bots !

Answer (score 0):

It could work but if the bot creator can see your web they can see that input and modify the bot.

I also think that [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html) is the best option.